# How do you open a .msu file?

Tags: windows, windows-update, file-types

How does one open an ".msu" file? I'm trying to install PowerShell 2.0 on Windows XP SP3. I read that you can use something called wusa.exe or a packet manager program?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307 ?

Comment: @Keith Thompson That link explains nothing...

Comment: From the linked page: "You can also double-click the .msu file to install the update package." Did you try that?

Comment: Please include the things you tried and how they failed. @KeithThompson's link is exactly what you are asking for. If the information there does not help, mention that you have read it and explain what happens when you try to follow MS's instructions. You might want to read [here](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask good questions on this and all sites on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use MSU files on Windows XP. This is the new Update format for Vista+.

You must use the `WindowsXP-KB968930-x86-ENG.exe` from here:

**Update for Windows XP (KB968930)**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16818

> **This package includes the following components: Windows PowerShell 2.0**
>   and Windows Remote Management (WinRM) 2.0. After you install this
>   item, you may have to restart your computer.

Comment: This should be marked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command to *open* the MSU file:

```
expand -f:* "file.msu" %temp%\ExtractFolder
```

Comment: `wusa.exe` is the program that will install these.  Typically you can double click on the `.msu` and `wusa.exe` will take over from there, otherwise try something like `c:\windows\system32\wusa.exe {path-to-msu-file}` from a command prompt.

Comment: Of course. My answer was more related to the first part of the original question "how to open," rather than "how to install."